# Return all values from row without column names in R

Tags: r, row, subset

I'm looking to return all values of a row in a data frame. However, this can't be done simply but subsetting as follows, because it also takes in the names of the columns.

```
df <- data.frame(person, salary, haircolor, outcome)
head(df)
          person salary haircolor  outcome
1       John Doe  21000     black  married
2     Peter Gynn  23400    blonde divorced
3     Jolie Hope  26800    blonde divorced

df_row1 <- df[1, ]
print(df_row)
>df_row1
  person   salary haircolor outcome
1 John Doe 21000  black     married
```

I need to create a vector for the first row values (without the column names). Actually, I'm looking to loop this through every row to create a vector for every row.

For example, I'm looking for the following for the first row:

```
print(df_row1_good)
>df_row1_good 
John Doe 21000  black     married
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to remove the names attributes, `unlist` and specify `use.names = FALSE`

```
unlist(df[1,], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "John Doe" "21000"    "black"    "married"
```

to print

```
cat(unlist(df[1,], use.names = FALSE), '\n')
#John Doe 21000 black married
```

Or `unname`

```
unname(df[1,])
```

Comment: The `unlist` function returns numeric values in my console. Do you know why this would produce different results for you and me?

Comment: @juansalsa The difference would be that if you have `factor` columns.  From `R 4.0`, by default ,`stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame` call or when reading with `read.csv/read.table`.  If you have a previous version, it would be TRUE i.e. strings will be `factor` and this gets coerced to numeric one.  You can do `unlist(type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)[1,], use.names = FALSE)`